# Are there any designs for fusion engines with similar performance to a nuclear lightbulb?

Tags: rockets, nuclear

Are there any fusion thrusters with a twr > 1 and an isp of a couple thousand seconds?

Comment: Check out http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/enginelist.php

Comment: @RussellBorogove Yeah, I've looked there before. Plenty of fission rockets with the desired performance, no fusion ones. It could be the nature of fusion makes it difficult to run in high-twr applications, but there must be some way of doing it.

Comment: There aren't even any *designs* for nuclear lightbulb *fission* engines.  The only fusion-powered rocket engines that got anywhere close to something you might call a design (and even that is generous) would be some of the Orion variants.

Comment: @pericynthion Okay, well, "concept" works then, instead of "design." There definitely are concepts for nuclear lightbulbs that a team of engineers could take and design a working prototype around the same idea. They'd need a lot of money and it would probably break several international laws, but it's definitely possible with today's technology (or a iterative improvement on it.).

Comment: If there is a fusion reactor on earth producing a lot of energy continously for many hours, we may think of fusion thrusters. But a fusion reactor with a very low mass would be necessary for a space application.